A quine that clones itself and runs some more quines
This is a follow-up to: A Quine program in C, where today I received the following suggestion:

Now, write the code so that the binary "clones" itself (makes a replica with an altered filename.) Eg: "./don" will lead to both "don" and "dan" in the directory. Then "./dan" will add "den" to the folder. Use whatever criteria you can imagine. Eg: Change only one vowel/consonant, change two. Reverse the characters of the filename. Rot13 the filename. "Buy a vowel" to insert into the filename... Then write the "controller" that iteratively gathers all the existing filenames and executes all of them. Another "evolution" program has been created... :-) Cheers! – Fe2O3

So that is exactly what I did.
Code:
There are around 100 lines of code, and the program assumes ASCII and POSIX, and yes, I skipped braces this one time:
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200819L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700

#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static char *clones[26];
static size_t clones_count;

void free_clones(void)
{
    while (clones_count--) {
        free(clones[clones_count]);
    }
}

char *caeser_cipher(unsigned int key, 
                    char dest[restrict static 1],
                    const char src[restrict static 1]) {
    char *p = dest;
    for (const unsigned char *c = (const unsigned char *)src; *c; ++c, ++p)
        if (isalpha(*c)) {
            char const pivot = isupper(*c) ? 'A' : 'a';
            *p = (*c - pivot + key) % 26 + pivot;
        } else {
            *p = *c;
        }
    *p = '\0';
    return dest;
}

bool copy_file(FILE dst[restrict static 1], FILE src[restrict static 1]) {
    struct stat st;
    
    /* Copy permissions, then copy contents. */
    if (fstat(fileno(src), &st) == -1
        || fchmod(fileno(dst), st.st_mode)) return false;

    char buf[65536];
    size_t n;

    while ((n = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, src)) > 0)
        if (fwrite(buf, 1, n, dst) != n)
            return false;
    return true;
}

FILE *open_new_clone(const char fpath[static 1]) {
    /* Allocate 2 extra bytes for adding "./" to the cloned binaries for passing
     * to execvp() later. */
    char *clone = malloc(strlen(fpath) + 3);    

    if (clone == nullptr) { return nullptr; }

    for (size_t i = 1; i < 26; ++i) {
        FILE *const f = fopen(caeser_cipher(i, clone + 2, fpath), "wx");

        if (f == nullptr) {
            if (errno != EEXIST) return f;
            clone[0] = '.';
            clone[1] = '/';
            clones[clones_count] = strdup(clone);
            
            if (clones[clones_count] == nullptr) {
            /* No recovery possible, so cleanup and exit. */
                perror("malloc()");
                free_clones();
                free(clone);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            ++clones_count;
            continue;
        }
        free(clone);
        return f;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

bool clone_file(const char fpath[static 1]) {
    FILE *file = {};
    FILE *clone_file = {};
    bool status = (file = fopen(fpath, "r"))
                  && (clone_file = open_new_clone(fpath))
                  && copy_file(clone_file, file);

    if (file)       fclose(file);
    if (clone_file) fclose(clone_file);
    return status;
}

void exec_clones(void) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < clones_count; ++i) {
        pid_t cpid = fork();

        switch (cpid) {
            case -1: perror("fork()"); return;  /* Ignore error. */
            case 0 : execvp(clones[i], (char *[]) {clones[i], nullptr}); _Exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            case 1 : wait(nullptr);
        }
    }
}

int main(int, char **argv) {
    clone_file(argv[0][0] == '.' && argv[0][1] == '/' ? argv[0] + 2 : argv[0]);

    static constexpr char code[] = "#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2008'19L\n#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700\n\n#include <ctype.h>\n#include <errno.h>\n#include <stddef.h>\n#include <stdio.h>\n#include <stdlib.h>\n#include <string.h>\n\n#include <fcntl.h>\n#include <sys/stat.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>\n#include <sys/wait.h>\n#include <unistd.h>\n\nstatic char *clones[26];\nstatic size_t clones_count;\n\nvoid free_clones(void)\n{\n    while (clones_count--) {\n        free(clones[clones_count]);\n    }\n}\n\nchar *caeser_cipher(unsigned int key, \n                    char dest[restrict static 1],\n                    const char src[restrict static 1]) {\n    char *p = dest;\n    for (const unsigned char *c = (const unsigned char *)src; *c; ++c, ++p)\n        if (isalpha(*c)) {\n            char const pivot = isupper(*c) ? 'A' : 'a';\n            *p = (*c - pivot + key) % 26 + pivot;\n        } else {\n            *p = *c;\n        }\n    *p = '\\0';\n    return dest;\n}\n\nbool copy_file(FILE dst[restrict static 1], FILE src[restrict static 1]) {\n    struct stat st;\n    \n    /* Copy permissions, then copy contents. */\n    if (fstat(fileno(src), &st) == -1\n        || fchmod(fileno(dst), st.st_mode)) return false;\n\n    char buf[65536];\n    size_t n;\n\n    while ((n = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, src)) > 0)\n        if (fwrite(buf, 1, n, dst) != n)\n            return false;\n    return true;\n}\n\nFILE *open_new_clone(const char fpath[static 1]) {\n    /* Allocate 2 extra bytes for adding \"./\" to the cloned binaries for passing\n     * to execvp() later. */\n    char *clone = malloc(strlen(fpath) + 3);    \n\n    if (clone == nullptr) { return nullptr; }\n\n    for (size_t i = 1; i < 26; ++i) {\n        FILE *const f = fopen(caeser_cipher(i, clone + 2, fpath), \"wx\");\n\n        if (f == nullptr) {\n            if (errno != EEXIST) return f;\n            clone[0] = '.';\n            clone[1] = '/';\n            clones[clones_count] = strdup(clone);\n            \n            if (clones[clones_count] == nullptr) {\n            /* No recovery possible, so cleanup and exit. */\n                perror(\"malloc()\");\n                free_clones();\n                free(clone);\n                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\n            }\n            ++clones_count;\n            continue;\n        }\n        free(clone);\n        return f;\n    }\n    return nullptr;\n}\n\nbool clone_file(const char fpath[static 1]) {\n    FILE *file = {};\n    FILE *clone_file = {};\n    bool status = (file = fopen(fpath, \"r\"))\n                  && (clone_file = open_new_clone(fpath))\n                  && copy_file(clone_file, file);\n\n    if (file)       fclose(file);\n    if (clone_file) fclose(clone_file);\n    return status;\n}\n\nvoid exec_clones(void) {\n    for (size_t i = 0; i < clones_count; ++i) {\n        pid_t cpid = fork();\n\n        switch (cpid) {\n            case -1: perror(\"fork()\"); return;  /* Ignore error. */\n            case 0 : execvp(clones[i], (char *[]) {clones[i], nullptr}); _Exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\n            case 1 : wait(nullptr);\n        }\n    }\n}\n\nint main(int, char **argv) {\n    clone_file(argv[0][0] == '.' && argv[0][1] == '/' ? argv[0] + 2 : argv[0]);\n\n    static constexpr char code[] = \"~\";\n\n    for (const char *p = code; *p; ++p)\n        if (*p == 0x7E) /* bitwise complement op */\n            for (const char *c = code; *c; ++c)\n                switch(*c) {\n                    case '\\n': putchar('\\\\'); putchar('n'); break;\n                    case '\\\\': putchar('\\\\'); putchar('\\\\'); break;\n                    case '\\\"' : putchar('\\\\'); putchar('\"'); break;\n                    default  : putchar(*c);\n                }\n        else putchar(*p);\n    exec_clones();\n    free_clones();\n}\n";

    for (const char *p = code; *p; ++p)
        if (*p == 0x7E) /* bitwise complement op */
            for (const char *c = code; *c; ++c)
                switch(*c) {
                    case '\n': putchar('\\'); putchar('n'); break;
                    case '\\': putchar('\\'); putchar('\\'); break;
                    case '\"' : putchar('\\'); putchar('"'); break;
                    default  : putchar(*c);
                }
        else putchar(*p);
    exec_clones();
    free_clones();
}

The acid test for the quine program is:
./quine | diff quine.c -

which passes for this program. Some might deem it a fork bomb, but it is just a simple quine of quines. Though, I wouldn't suggest running the executable more than once. If you do - and when you get hold of your system - you may run:
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable | xargs rm

Assuming there weren't any other executables already present in the same directory, this would get rid of the original executable and its clones.
The first run doesn't actually execute any clones, but only outputs the program's source code innocently.
Review Request:
Anything. Everything.
I used Caesar's cipher so that it would be trivial for the "controller" to gather all existing filenames. Though I am open to using a better algorithm, given that it would not complicate the gathering process.
65536 as a magic number is obvious, but 26 is not. What'd be a good name for it?

A good name for 26 clones? It might require an explanatory comment, but A2Z works for me. (I like cryptic :-))

I hope you were chuckling when putting this together.
One reads that the best learning and growing occurs during play.

Use a NULL sentinel instead?
static char *clones[26];
static size_t clones_count;

Taking a page from the *argv[] paradigm, the global (no comment) array clones[] is filled (or partially filled?) contiguously with pointers. The entire app could work with that array analogous to a null terminated C string; clones_count would then be redundant. Example:
void free_clones( void ) {
    for( size_t i = 0; clones[i]; ) free( clones[ i++ ] );
}


Antici..............pation
open_new_clone() may be trying to do too much. Currently

grab a buffer big enough for the needs of execvp()
pass that buffer (offset) to caeser_cypher() where it will be partly filled
then some jiggery-pokery that mashes up byte copying, strdup(), return codes and FILE ptrs, multiple returns, a continue, and even an exit(), all while possibly iterating 25 times.I've been sick on rollercoaster rides that were a lot tamer than that Gordian Knot.

For instance: postpone the ./ prefixing until needed in exec_clones() where a local (stack) temporary buffer could be used.
char tbuf[MAX_PATH] = "./"; // or some such
strcat( tbuf, fname );
execvp( ...

Additionally, if upon entry, open_new_clone() were merely to strdup() a working copy of its parameter string (or be passed a working buffer for its use), then caeser_cypher() could merely walk the string once, substituting character-by-character as appropriate.
Let each worker function do its own job, keeping its fingers out of the tasks that others will be performing. Centralisation increases complexity.

Style options (for your consideration)
bool copy_file(FILE dst[restrict static 1], FILE src[restrict static 1]) {
// 1
    if (fstat(fileno(src), &st) == -1
        || fchmod(fileno(dst), st.st_mode)) return false;
// 2
    if (fstat(fileno(src), &st) == -1 || fchmod(fileno(dst), st.st_mode))
        return false;
// 3
    if( fstat(  fileno( src ), &st ) == -1
    ||  fchmod( fileno( dst ), st.st_mode ) )
        return false;
// 4
    if( fstat(  fileno( src ), &st ) == -1 )  return false;
    if( fchmod( fileno( dst ), st.st_mode ) ) return false;


#1 is the existing code
#2 rearranges the logic (note line length)
#3 is a style I've adopted to help my old eyes parse tokens
#4 is a super simple alternative that shouldn't be overlooked

An auto formatter wouldn't like the forced vertical alignment of the two fileno( calls.However, an auto formatter isn't responsible for verifying the semantics of the code.I say, "Poo-poo on auto formatting!!"

Magic char buf[65536]; and some code golf
That constant really should be something like x * BUF_SIZE (right token??).
bool copy_file() contains 4 lines of very recognisable processing, copying bucketloads of bytes from one file to another.
Recognising that the meaning of local variable names comes-and-goes quickly as the reader scans the code, shortening the few variables may aid expressing the logic. Worker functions need to justify using more than a very few variables. Reason and a comment can serve in place of longer lines that may or may not be easily grokked.
    const size_t sz = 16 * BUF_SIZ; size_t n; // 'n' cannot be 'const'...
    char b[sz];
    while( (n=fread(b, 1, sz, s)) && fwrite(b, 1, n, d)==n ) {}
    return n == 0;

Note: there's no error handling/reporting happening here.

Not sure why the source code is 'quining` itself, but I'll leave that for another day.

"there's no error handling/reporting happening here." I did not think that necessary, as the main purpose is to still act as a quine. But perhaps then I should also remove perror("fork()");.

Necessary is what the author wants to achieve when it comes to these "fun" projects, imho... I was just being a stickler as I've not had enough caffeine yet today... Cheers! :-)

Looks like none of the prefixing with ./ was needed. I simply replaced execvp() with exec().

"Additionally, if upon entry, open_new_clone() were merely to strdup() a working copy of its parameter string (or be passed a working buffer for its use), then caeser_cypher() could merely walk the string once, substituting character-by-character as appropriate." ==> Is that not what it currently not? I did not understand this part.

Actually, neither did I, really... There's a lot happening in that function, with replication of strings being only one part... Trivial aside: Couldn't a "working copy" of the string be passed to caeser()? Transformation "in place", without copying byte by byte from source to destination... Sorry... I kinda became a little muddled about what was happening when/where...

https://github.com/Melkor-1/quine/blob/main/quine4.c is what the final version looks like.

@Harith Looks impressive! :-) "FREE THE CLONES!! FREE THE CLONES!!" :-) Congratulations on the bravery of using goto, seriously! There are so many "do's and don'ts" that one hears through life that really need to be examined (and cast aside.) Kudos! Hoping you've had some chuckles from that random notion... Cheers! :-)... (I'm biding my time waiting for someone to say more than "code golf" regarding my recent posts here... There's a marvellous answer to one of my posts that is "under development." All I can say is, "Fore!!!" :-))

I use goto for such error-handling all the time. Perhaps when defer arrives, I will not have to use goto, though there's nothing wrong with it. As of getting proper reviews, C does not get much attention on CodeReview, unlike StackOverflow. I have found that the ones who review C code here tend to only look at things that are not very large (say less than 400-500K lines), or code that is deemed clever and hard to understand for the layman C coder. Though small snippets like "implementing strcpy()" et cetera tend to get a lot of attention here. Mostly it is Python, C++, and Java here.
